# How can I see my Azure SQL Server Admin Password?

Tags: passwords, azure-sql-database

I am an admin for an Azure SQL Server, however I don't know the password anymore. Is there any way I can find it? I tried to do it via Azure UI and the only possibility I am seeing is to reset the password and I don't want this.

Answer (score 1):

No, and such a feature would be a security risk. If you've forgotten your password and didn't store it somewhere safe (in your password management software, for example) it is lost. You'll need to reset it, and this time, remember to store it somewhere **secure** as well.